# Set socket opt failed bad file number exception

Tags: java, android, sockets

Am getting set socket option failed exception in Android. What am I doing wrong ?

```
    setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
```

For the following code:

```
int timeout = 500;



Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),
                            Integer.parseInt(m.destPort));
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(m);
                    oos.close();
                    socket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);
                    ObjectInputStream iis = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    iis.readObject();
                    iis.close();
                    socket.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Closing the input or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Change

```
oos.close();
```

to

```
oos.flush();
```

(Poor coding in Android. It should throw a `SocketException: socket closed.`)